# not getting any POST response in ajax with node application

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I have this AJAX method and here I am importing a CSV file but I am not able to get any response the same code is executing in LINUX OS whenever I am trying to try in windows it is not working means not sending in response

**AJAX method:**

```
 uploadUsers: function(data) {
     return $.ajax({
         url: "/api/importusers",
         type: "POST",
         data: data,
         contentType: false,
         cache: false, 
         processData: false,
     })
 }
```

**AJAX Code:**

```
$('#upload-users-frm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData(this)
    app.uploadUsers(data).done(function (response) {
        if ($.validateResponse(response)) {
            if (response.status == true) {
                if (response.message != '') {
                    Materialize.toast(response.message, 4000, '')
                }

                if (response.importError == true) {

                    $.showValidationMessage(response.ImportErrorMessage)
                }
            } else {
                $.showValidationMessage(response.message)
            }
        }
    })
})
```

**Form Code:**

```
<form id="upload-users-frm">
    <div class="file-field input-field">
        <div class="btn">
            <span>Upload Users</span>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="upload-user" 
                   class="import-file" accept=".csv, 
                   application/vnd.openxmlformats-o 
                   fficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel">
        </div>
        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
            <input class="file-path validate import-file" type="text" > 
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: In server side, does your request receive and handle correctly?

Comment: check your request object to the function handling POST request to your API `/api/importusers' on server side. 
if yes, Check your browser if its trying to block your Ajax request

Comment: actually i am using adonisjs ,so there is a method which allows some particular extension , so i added this extension 'vnd.ms-excel' then this works fine thank you for your support and suggestion